# Magento-ify SQL SELECT

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I want to dig deeper into Magentos SQL adapter. There are a lot of answer that often suggests to use Magentos own implementation of the SQL-Adapter.

I currently want to do this SQL in a resource Model:

```
SELECT pd.sku 
FROM wishlist_item AS wl 
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity AS pd
ON pd.entity_id = wl.product_id
WHERE wl.wishlist_id = 2;
```

How would I transform that into Magento Code if I shall not use `->query($query)`?

Comment: are you fine with using `Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');`?

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš Sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its always a good idea to use query generators instead of RAW queries (security issues)

```
$connection        = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$catalogTable      = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product');
$wishlistItemTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('whistlist/item');

$sql = $connection->select()->from(
     ["wi" => $wishlistItemTable], 
     []
)->join(
    ["cpe" => $catalogTable],
    'cpe.entity_id = wi.product_id',
    ['sku']
)->where(
    'wi.wishlist_id = ?', 2
);

$connection->fetchCol($sql);
```

1. Use `getTableName()` method to get proper table names (for cases
   where database table prefixing is enabled)
2. Using `fetchCol()` as there is only one column required in the query result. There are quite a few like `fetchPairs()`,`fetchRow()`, `fetchOne()` etc depends on the query result type, should not always `fetchAll()` unless necessary

Comment: That sounds very good to me. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This answer returns `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) ` instead of the SKUS. The SQL still returns the correct result.

Comment: the `fetchCol` should only be used when fetching a single column from the table, you might have multiple columns

Answer (score 4):

Try Below code that will work for you

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('whistlist/item')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('wishlist_id', 2);

$collection->getSelect()
     ->joinLeft(
          array('product'=> Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product')),
          'product.entity_id = main_table.product_id',
           array('pid'=>'product.product_id'));
```

Comment: For further readability you should try to format your code :)

Comment: @Max Is it readable now? and also feel free to edit if you are not changing content

Comment: @Max you are always welcome